# Why do Scala Ints lack the postfix increment operator, but HashMaps don't?

Tags: scala

Many data types in scala, like HashMaps, have the postfix increment operator implemented, but Ints and Doubles have not.

Is it because if there was a postfix operator for numbers, there had to be a prefix operator too, and that would not fit the way operators are implemented in scala (as methods)?

Comment: What does a `HashMap`'s post-increment do? You're not talking about the `++` method to merge two `HashMap` instances, are you?

Comment: @MatthiasMeid Yes I do. I also find it a bit odd they chose this operator for merge operation.

Comment: I wouldn't consider that one a *postfix-increment*, even though it is `++` too: Increment operators are typically unary (like `i++` or `++i`), whereas `map1 ++ map2` needs two maps *and does something different*. So see my answer for an attempt to explain why there's no `i++`, and let's see whether there are better answers coming up... :)

Comment: @MatthiasMeid IIRC it's the operator used in haskell for List concatenation.

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes, and in Scala too (for sets and lists).

Comment: @AdamS: There is no postfix increment operator on `HashMap`. Can you please clarify your question? What does *incrementing* a `HashMap` even *mean*?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Maybe I expressed this question a bit wrong. I just meant the postfix `++` operator, that is used for incrementation in many other programming languages. It was more meant like "When there generally is usage of the postfix ++ in scala, why doesn't Ints have it?". The answer from axel22 is exactly clarifies it for me.

Comment: @AdamS: That answer is about the *infix* `++` operator, not the *postfix* `++` operator.

Comment: It states that the operator `++` is generally used in scala for union, not incrementation. It's therefore clear that this operator does not share the functionality with the postfix/prefix `++` from other languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `++` operator is not meant as an imperative increment operator, but as a union of two collection, such that it produces new collections instead of modifying either of the old ones.

Comment: This is applied to all the scala standard library?

Comment: This is the idiom mainly seen in the collections part of the standard library, yes. Also a `grep` on the Scala repo can show that `++` is in general meant as non-side-effecting union operation. Note that this is different from `++=` on mutable collections which adds all the elements of the right hand side collection into the mutable collection on the left.

Comment: In other words, the `++` method on Scala collections does not have anything to do with the postfix `++` operator that exists in Java and other programming languages - it just happens to have the same name.

Comment: @Jesper: actually, not even that. In particular, it *isn't* postfix, it's infix.

Answer (score 2):

The increment operator is a very *imperatively styled* thing. I think (!) as you're encouraged to program in a *functional style*, where variable values are not supposed to change in general, it is not present in Scala.

However, this is highly unofficially what I think from a Scala programmer point of view.